# nls() gradient error in fitting growth curve data

Tags: r, nls, growth-model

I am trying to model the following data on promotional budget and customer awareness. The idea is, at some point, increase in budget doesn't have any further impact on awareness; it saturates.

```
> promo
  budget aware
1    0.7     8
2    0.8    11
3    0.9    16
4    1.0    21
5    1.1    22
6    1.4    31
7    1.5    36
8    2.0    45
9    3.0    50
```

Beyond `promo$budget=3.0`, there won't be any returns. A plot of the budget and aware shows a growth curve that looks a bit like [Gompertz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function#Formula).

[image: Budget vs. Awareness]

So, I tried something like this:

```
f <- nls(aware ~ A*exp(-1*b*exp(-1*c*budget)), data=promo, start=list(A=4,b=1,c=-2))
```

It results in this error:

```
Error in nls(aware ~ A * exp(-1 * b * exp(-1 * c * budget)), data = promo,  : singular gradient
```

How do I fit the growth curve to this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a self-starting model:

```
promo <- read.table(text = "  budget aware
1    0.7     8
2    0.8    11
3    0.9    16
4    1.0    21
5    1.1    22
6    1.4    31
7    1.5    36
8    2.0    45
9    3.0    50")

f <- nls(aware ~ SSgompertz(budget, Asym, b2, b3), data=promo)

plot(aware ~ budget, data = promo)
curve(predict(f, newdata = data.frame(budget = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image: resulting plot showing the data and the model fit]

Note that `SSgompertz` uses a different parameterization, see `help("SSgompertz")`. However, your problem are the starting values. For instance, you start with an asymptote value of 4, which obviously is far from the actual value. If I set `start = list(A = 50, b = 0.1, c = 1)` I get a successful (and identical) fit with your parameterization.

Comment: Awesome! In the meantime, I was referring to the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160575/104075 where, an exponential curve fit, between y=Budget and x=Aware is used. I get a convergence tolerance of 6.202e-06 which is greater than the tolerance in this curve (4.533e-07). Plus, I *know* this is a phenomenon where the awareness variable will saturate. So, I guess, this model is better than the exponential model.