# Is there a clean way to derive the start parameters for running the `fitdist()` function for the Gumbel distribution?

Tags: r, survival, gumbel-distribution

I've begun working with the Gumbel distribution and started with the example in the package documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/fitdistrplus.pdf. For the Gumbel distribution `fitdist()` requires start parameters (template is `fitdist(data, distr, method = c(...), start=NULL,...)`), where it's described as "*A named list giving the initial values of parameters of the named distribution or a function of data computing initial values and returning a named list. This argument may be omitted (default) for some distributions for which reasonable starting values are computed...*" Gumbel is not on the list of distributions where start parameters may be omitted. In the below code I use the start parameters from the reference manual example and it works, but that's random. If I use start parameters of `start = list(1,1)` for example the function doesn't work.

Is there a way to generate these start parameters automatically? When I find start parameters that work the output is indifferent for example whether I use (5,5) or (500,500), so a hack solution would be to randomly generate parameter values until the function works. But I'm hoping for a cleaner, non-hack solution.

By the way I realize Gumbel is not a good fit for `lung` dataset! I'm just using `lung` for sake of example.

Code:

```
library(evd)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(survival)

# Gumbel distribution
time <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)
deathTime <- lung$time[lung$status == 1]
fitGum <- fitdist(deathTime, "gumbel",start=list(a=10,b=10)) 
survGum <- 1-evd::pgumbel(time, fitGum$estimate[1], fitGum$estimate[2])

plot(time,survGum,type="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Survival Probability", main="Lung Survival")
lines(survGum, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 3) # plot Gumbel
```

Comment: A general answer to this question is provided in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552.  For distribution fitting specifically, people often use simple but potentially inferior methods to obtain initial estimates: consider method of moments or methods based on order statistics, for instance.  There's still no guarantee, because (as you note) when the distribution is a poor description of the data, all bets are off.

Comment: Following @whuber, method of moments seems pretty simple for this distribution. Using the moment equations from wikipedia, we would have $s=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\pi}\sigma$ and $l=\mu-\gamma s$ as our initial values, where $l,s$ are the location and scale parameters (as parameterized by wiki), $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the sample mean and stdev, and $\gamma\approx 0.57$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. (I have not double checked this math).

Comment: @JohnMadden that's for the maximum extreme value form. There's always ambiguity when someone just says "Gumbel distribution" or "extreme value distribution" without also specifying "maximum" or "minimum." I suspect that the "minimum" form is at issue here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [NIST page on Gumbel distributions](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366g.htm) shows the [method of moments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/method-of-moments/info) estimators for the parameters of both the maximum and minimum extreme-value distributions. Those are easily calculated and should provide reliable initial estimates.

The parameterization of the density function for the minimum extreme value distribution on that page is:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\beta} \exp({\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}})\exp({-\exp({\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}}}))$$

with location parameter $\mu$ and scale parameter $\beta$.

In that parameterization, with sample mean $\bar X$ and sample standard deviation $s$, the method of moments estimators are:

$$\tilde{\beta}=\frac{s\sqrt6}{\pi}$$

and:

$$\tilde{\mu}=\bar X +0.5772 \tilde{\beta} $$

where 0.5772 is an approximation to [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

That's used by `survreg()` in R, which you can see by typing the following at the command prompt:

```
survival::survreg.distributions$extreme$init
```

Answer (score 6):

Putting EdM's answer into code, which seems to work well and is very concise:

```
library(evd)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(survival)

time <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)
deathTime <- lung$time[lung$status == 2]

scale_est <- (sd(deathTime)*sqrt(6))/pi
loc_est <- mean(deathTime) + 0.5772157*scale_est

fitGum <- fitdist(deathTime, "gumbel",start=list(a = loc_est, b = scale_est)) 
survGum <- 1-evd::pgumbel(time, fitGum$estimate[1], fitGum$estimate[2])

plot(time,survGum,type="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Survival Probability", main="Lung Survival")
lines(survGum, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 3) # plot Gumbel
```

**Alternative:** in referencing [Why is nls() giving me "singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates" errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates) per whuber's comment, which says to paraphrase: "*Automatically finding good starting values for a nonlinear model is an art. (It's relatively easy for one-off datasets when you can just plot the data and make some good guesses visually.) One approach is to **linearize the model and use least squares estimates**.*" I came up with the following which appears to work in this case.

```
library(evd)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(survival)

time <- seq(0, 1000, by = 1)
deathTime <- lung$time[lung$status == 2]

# Define the linearized model
linearized_model <- function(time, a, b) {
  log_time <- log(time)
  log_time - a / b
}

# Define the objective function for least squares estimation
objective_function <- function(params) {
  a <- params[1]
  b <- params[2]
  predicted_values <- linearized_model(deathTime, a, b)
  residuals <- predicted_values - log(deathTime)
  sum(residuals^2)
}

# Least squares estimation to obtain starting parameters
starting_params <- optim(c(1, 1), objective_function)$par

fitGum <- fitdist(deathTime, "gumbel",start=list(a = starting_params[1], b = starting_params[2])) 
survGum <- 1-evd::pgumbel(time, fitGum$estimate[1], fitGum$estimate[2])

plot(time,survGum,type="n",xlab="Time",ylab="Survival Probability", main="Lung Survival")
lines(survGum, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 3) # plot Gumbel
```